# How to update array object within reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**TLDR: How to update array object within the reducer**

I would need some help understanding how to update the like count value of my post data once the action has been fired, and possibly a working logic.

Posts are being fetched from an action, being passed and mapped as a posts prop. Ideally it should make a new likes object on upvote

A user is able to click like, and on the backend its adds a like. Which is good.
The front end needs to upvote the current value to plus +1, however the current logic is not working.

Getting this error with current logic

> there seem to be an error TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread
>   non-iterable instance

`console.log(index)` renders the like count for whatever post the user clicked on.

for example like

> 20

I would not be able to use state, i would need to do this in redux.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N0Nh.png <- idea of what the front end looks like

*Here is the Posts Structure*

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "React Interview Questiossssnsdd",
  "post_content": "ssss",
  "username": "blueowl",
  "createdAt": "2019-04-26T09:38:10.324Z",
  "updatedAt": "2019-04-26T18:55:39.319Z",
  "userId": 1,
  "Likes": [
    {
      "id": 131,
      "like": true,
      "createdAt": "2019-04-26T12:20:58.251Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-04-26T12:20:58.251Z",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 152,
      "like": true,
      "createdAt": "2019-04-26T14:01:13.347Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-04-26T14:01:13.347Z",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 153,
      "like": true,
      "createdAt": "2019-04-26T14:01:46.739Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-04-26T14:01:46.739Z",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5
    },...
```

*Example Likes Structure*

```
[
  {
    "id": 182,
    "like": true,
    "createdAt": "2019-04-27T11:05:05.612Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T11:05:05.612Z",
    "userId": 1,
    "postId": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 178,
    "like": true,
    "createdAt": "2019-04-27T10:44:49.311Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T10:44:49.311Z",
    "userId": 1,
    "postId": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 179,
    "like": true,
    "createdAt": "2019-04-27T10:45:27.380Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T10:45:27.380Z",
    "userId": 1,
    "postId": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 180,
    "like": true,
    "createdAt": "2019-04-27T10:46:44.260Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T10:46:44.260Z",
    "userId": 1,
    "postId": 5
  },
```

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[],
    isEditing:false,
    isEditingId:null,
    likes:[],
    someLike:[],
    postId:null
}


export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case GET_POSTS:
      console.log(action.data)
      return {
         ...state, 
        posts: action.data, // maps posts fine,
      }

    case ADD_LIKE:
        console.log(action.id) // renders post id
        // console.log(state.posts) // logs posts array
        console.log(state.posts)

        const index = state.posts.find((post) => post.id === action.id).Likes.length 
        console.log(index); // gets likes length for the corresponding id to whatever post that has been clickd
        // renders 5 or 3 (their is currently 2 posts)
        // honestly don't what im doing below this line of code but should make a new like object
        return [
        {
            Likes: [
                ...state.posts.find((post) => post.id === action.id).Likes.length + 1,
                action.newLikeObject
            ]
         }    
      ]
```

show update count below here

`myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here`

```
    render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;    // from reducer   
        return (
          <div>
            {posts.map(post => (

              <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                <PostItem
                  myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here
                  myTitle={this.state.title}
                  editChange={this.onChange}
                  editForm={this.formEditing}
                  isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id}
                  removePost={this.removePost}
                  {...post}

                />
              </Paper>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**extra info**

**actions.js**

```
export const postLike = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        // console.log(userId);
        return Axios.post('/api/posts/like', {
            postId: id
        }).then( (like) => {

            dispatch({type: ADD_LIKE, id})
                // console.log('you have liked this', like)
        }).catch( (err)=> {
                console.log('there seem to be an error', err);
        })

    }
}
```

Edit

`console.log(newState)`

```
{
  "post": [],
  "postError": null,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": "React Interview Questiossssnsdd",
      "post_content": "ssss",
      "username": "EliHood",
      "createdAt": "2019-04-26T09:38:10.324Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-04-26T18:55:39.319Z",
      "userId": 1,
      "Likes": [
        {
          "id": 219,
          "like": true,
          "createdAt": "2019-04-27T15:54:03.841Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T15:54:03.841Z",
          "userId": 1,
          "postId": 5
        },
        {
          "id": 189,
          "like": true,
          "createdAt": "2019-04-27T11:11:07.558Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T11:11:07.558Z",
          "userId": 1,
          "postId": 5
        },
        {
          "id": 190,
          "like": true,
          "createdAt": "2019-04-27T11:12:09.599Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T11:12:09.599Z",
          "userId": 1,
          "postId": 5
        },
        ....,
  "isEditing": false,
  "isEditingId": null,
  "likes": [
    77,
    24
  ],
  "someLike": [],
  "postId": null
}
```

**Like Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee, faAdjust } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {  postLike} from '../actions/';
class Like extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            likes: null,
            heart: false
        }
    }

    //  passes post id thats stored in PostItem.js
    clickLike = (id) => {
        this.props.postLike(id);
        // toggles between css class
        this.setState({
            heart: !this.state.heart
        })
    }
    render(){
       return(
            <div style={{float:'right', fontSize: '1.5em', color:'tomato'}} >
            <i style={{ marginRight: '140px'}} className={this.state.heart ? 'fa fa-heart':'fa fa-heart-o' }>
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: '6px'}}>
                        <a href="#" onClick={() =>this.clickLike(this.props.like)}>Like</a>   

                    </span>
                    {/* gets the like counts */}
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: '7px'}} >{this.props.likes}  </span>  

                </i>
            </div>       
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,

})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id))
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Like);
```

Like component being passed here as  `<Like like={id} likes={myLikes} />`

**PostItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import Editable from './Editable';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {UpdatePost, postLike, getCount} from '../actions/';
import Like from './Like';
import Axios from '../Axios';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    },
    button:{
        marginRight:'30px'
    }
}
class PostItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            disabled: false,
            myId: 0,
            likes:0
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){

    }
    onUpdate = (id, title) => () => {
        // we need the id so expres knows what post to update, and the title being that only editing the title. 
        if(this.props.myTitle !== null){
            const creds = {
                id, title
            }
            this.props.UpdatePost(creds); 
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {title, id, userId, removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange, myTitle, postUpdate, Likes, clickLike, myLikes} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                   <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                   {/* if else teneray operator */}
                   {isEditing ? (
                          <Editable editField={myTitle ? myTitle : title} editChange={editChange}/>
                   ): (
                       <div>
                           {title}
                       </div>    
                   )}         
                   </Typography>
                   <Typography  component={'span'} variant={'body2'}>
                       {post_content}
                       <h5>by: {username} </h5>
                       {/*  component span cancels out the cant be a decedent of error */}
                       <Typography  component={'span'} variant={'body2'} color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                      {/* gets like counts */}
                       <Like like={id} likes={myLikes} /> 
                   </Typography>
                   {!isEditing ? (
                       <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                           Edit
                       </Button>
                   ):(     
                       // pass id, and myTitle which as we remember myTitle is the new value when updating the title
                        <div>
                            <Button 
                                disabled={myTitle.length <= 3}
                                variant="outlined" 
                                onClick={this.onUpdate(id, myTitle)}>
                                Update
                            </Button>
                            <Button 
                                variant="outlined" 
                                style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                                onClick={editForm(null)}>
                                Close
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                   )}
                   {!isEditing && (
                    <Button
                        style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={removePost(id)}>
                        Remove
                    </Button>
                    )}
           </div>
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,

})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),

    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostItem);
```

**Posts.js** (Master parent)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {GetPosts} from '../actions/';
const Styles = {
    myPaper:{
      margin: '20px 0px',
      padding:'20px'
    }
    , 
    wrapper:{
      padding:'0px 60px'
    }
}
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    loading: true,
    isEditing: false, 
    // likes:[]
  }
  async componentWillMount(){
    await this.props.GetPosts();

    const thesePosts = await this.props.myPosts
    const myPosts2 = await thesePosts
    // const filtered = myPosts2.map((post) => post.Likes )
    // const likesCount = filtered.map( (like) => like.length)
    this.setState({
      posts: myPosts2,
      loading:false
    })



  }


  render() {
    const {loading} = this.state;
    const { myPosts} = this.props
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }
    if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }
    return (
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList posts={this.state.posts}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  myPosts: state.post.posts,


})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => ({
  GetPosts: () => dispatch( GetPosts())
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Posts));
```

**PostList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost, postLike, UpdatePost,EditChange, GetPosts,  getCount, DisableButton} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
import _ from 'lodash';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            title: '',
            loading:true,
            posts:[],

        }
    } 

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.GetPosts();
        const ourPosts = this.props.myPosts
       this.setState({
         posts: ourPosts,
         loading:false
       })

       console.log(this.state.posts)
     }
     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const hasNewLike = false;
        if(this.state.posts && this.state.posts.length) {
          for(let index=0; index < nextProps.myPosts.length; index++) {
          if(nextProps.myPosts[index].Likes.length != 
           this.state.posts[index].Likes.length) {
             hasNewLike = true;

          }
        }
      }
      if(hasNewLike) {
       this.setState({posts: nextProps.myPosts});  // here we are updating the posts state if redux state has updated value of likes
      }
      console.log(nextProps.myPosts)
     }

    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }
    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {;
        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }



    render(){
        // const {posts, ourLikes, likes} = this.props;

        // console.log(posts)
        // console.log(this.props.ourLikes);
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.posts.map(post => (

              <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                <PostItem
                  myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here
                  myTitle={this.state.title}
                  editChange={this.onChange}
                  editForm={this.formEditing}
                  isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id}
                  removePost={this.removePost}
                  {...post}

                />
              </Paper>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    myPosts: state.post.posts,
    // ourLikes: state.post.likes // reducer likes 
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),
    GetPosts: () => dispatch( GetPosts()),

    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems be occurring due to the code below

`...state.posts.find((post) => post.id === action.id).Likes.length + 1`

so here, we are finding the length of **likes** whose result will be a number and then we are trying to spread a number type variable, but **spread** operator (...) works for **iterables** like object, array.

From what I understand we want to update the **likes** array in **posts** collection.

```
case ADD_LIKE:
        const newState = {...state};  // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state
        newState.posts.find(post => post.id == action.id).Likes.push(action.newLikeObject); // here we are trying to append the new like object to already existing **likes** array in the **posts** which should now make the count increase by 1

        return newState;
```

if we want to use spread operator to update the array, we can use as below:

```
case ADD_LIKE:
        const newState = {...state};  // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
        const existingLikesOfPost = newState.posts.find(post => post.id == action.id).Likes;
        newState.posts.find(post => post.id == action.id).Likes = [...existingLikesOfPost, action.newLikeObject]; // using this approach I got some code duplication so I suggested the first approach of using **push** method of array.
       return newState;
```

In Posts.js we can add another lifecycle method, like below:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   const hasNewLike = false;
   if(this.state.posts && this.state.posts.length) {
     for(let index=0; index < nextProps.myPosts.length; index++) {
     if(nextProps.myPosts[index].Likes.length != 
      this.state.posts[index].Likes.length) {
        hasNewLike = true;

     }
   }
 }
 if(hasNewLike) {
  this.setState({posts: nextProps.myPosts});  // here we are updating the posts state if redux state has updated value of likes
 }
}
```

edited above solution to use componentWillrecieveProps instead of getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192486/discussion-on-answer-by-anuradha-kumari-how-to-update-array-object-within-reduce).

Answer (score 0):

You're currently trying to spread an integer with the following line:

```
...state.posts.find((post) => post.id === action.id).Likes.length + 1,
```

(you shouldn't try and modify an array's `length` property directly like this, if that's what you were trying to do)

Modifying deeply nested objects like this is pretty annoying without a library like `ramda`, but I think you're looking for something like this in your return statement:

```
// copy your state's posts
const newPosts = [...state.posts]

// Find the post you're adding a like to
const idx = newPosts.findIndex((post) => post.id === action.id)
const postToReplace = newPosts[idx]

// Replace that post with a copy...
newPosts[idx] = {
    ...postToReplace,
    // ... with the Likes object also copied, with the new Like appended.
    Likes: [
        ...postToReplace.Likes,
        action.newLikeObject
    ]
}

return {
    ...state,
    posts: newPosts
}
```

Basically, you need to drill down into your object and start replacing the elements that you're affecting in an immutable way.

Comment: thanks for answering :) Im not using  `this.props.likes` though im just using `{post.Likes.length}` as the prop but would this solution be able to upvote the value i don't see a `+1`

Comment: in the return statement, just want to make sure you know what i wanted to accomplish

Comment: Ah, I see, your initial state and your post structure are kind of in conflict.  I know what you're after; I'll make an edit in a bit.

Comment: Thank you Dylan. Been stuck on this for days

Comment: about to give this a shot.

Comment: this still doesn't add a + 1 on the current value though. Thank you for your explanation. It does make sense though.

Comment: `const idx = newPosts.findIndex((post) => post.id === action.id)` gives me 0 in the console.log

Comment: maybe if i change `findIndex` to `find`

Comment: `const idx = newPosts.find((post) => post.id === action.id).id`
            `console.log(idx)` gives me an existing post id like 5. However it still didn't fix the upvote count issue